# ClassCircularityError on Logback FilterReply

Tags: java, jetty, classloader

We have faced some really weird behavior of Java class loading mechanism. I'm getting `ClassCircularityError` when implementing Logback's `TurboFilter`. I have following simple implementation:

```
public class ActivatingTurboFilter extends TurboFilter {

  [...]
  @Override
  public FilterReply decide(Marker marker, Logger logger,
                            Level level, String format, Object[] params,
                            Throwable t) {
    if (!expectedValue.equals(MDC.get(key)))
      return NEUTRAL;
    return isLevelAndLoggerValid(level, logger.getName()) ? ACCEPT : NEUTRAL;
  }
}
```

Application is deployed as a WAR-file on Jetty/9.2.10. When `decide()` method is called I got:

```
java.lang.ClassCircularityError: ch/qos/logback/core/spi/FilterReply
    at me.bazhenov.whisperer.ActivatingTurboFilter.decide(ActivatingTurboFilter.java:33)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.TurboFilterList.getTurboFilterChainDecision(TurboFilterList.java:62)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.getTurboFilterChainDecision_0_3OrMore(LoggerContext.java:252)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callTurboFilters(Logger.java:772)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.isTraceEnabled(Logger.java:644)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.isTraceEnabled(Logger.java:640)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.isTraceEnabled(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:60)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport.handleTransportFailure(FailoverTransport.java:208)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport$3.onException(FailoverTransport.java:186)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onException(WireFormatNegotiator.java:160)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.onException(InactivityMonitor.java:255)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.onException(TransportSupport.java:96)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Some additional information:

- exception is thrown on `ActivatingTurboFilter.java:33` which is line where `FilterReply. NEUTRAL` is returned;
- on the moment of method call, enum `FilterReply` is already loaded. It's confirmed using `-verbose:class` logging and instance count from `jmap -histo`;
- Logback (ver. 1.1.2) is *not* part of application, but part of Jetty installation. So it's located in `lib` directory inside Jetty home dir.
- there is *only one* instance of Logback provided to application (and only one definition of `FilterReply` available, as a result). Confirmed using `-verbose:class` logging, as well as `find . -name \*.jar | xargs -n 1 zipinfo | grep -i FilterReply` (in Jetty home dir *and* content of a WAR-file).

I suspect that there is something weird with Jetty class loading going on, because all works fine if I call this method in any thread but Jetty request-processing threads (so called `qtp` threads).

I'm running out of ideas where to look for a reason.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?